# Google Custom Search Engine Error

Tags: css, html, single-sign-on, google-custom-search

I am building a website that will be used internally at my workplace. It is hosted on a company server. Users will have to login via SSO before they can access this html site. I was exploring adding the google custom search engine to the website but I keep getting the following error. Not certain what is causing it. Is it the fact that its hosted internally or something else? That’s an error.

404

```
The requested URL /cse?cref=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Fcse%2Ftools%2Fmakecse%3Furl%3Dfile%253A%252F%252F%252FUsers%252Famandeepsingh%252FDesktop%252520Website%252FGateway%252520Team%252520Website%252Fhome.html&ie=UTF-8&hl=&q=actual&sa=Search&siteurl=%2FUsers%2Famandeepsingh%2FDesktop%2520Website%2FGateway%2520Team%2520Website%2Fhome.html&ref=&ss=876j140290j7 was not found on this server.`
```

That’s all we know.

Comment: After decoding the URL I see this (a local path?) https://www.google.com/cse/tools/makecse?url=file:///Users/amandeepsingh/Desktop Website/Gateway Team Website/home.html&ie=UTF-8&hl=&q=actual&sa=Search&siteurl=/Users/amandeepsingh/Desktop Website/Gateway Team Website/home.html&ref=&ss=876j140290j7

Comment: Yes, although I get a similar error on the live site as well. Any ideas what might be causing it?

Comment: I think If the site is hosted internally it cannot be index or used together with Google custom search when there is no access from outside. I think that is not what Google custom search can be used for. What do you think?

Comment: That is what I suspected as well. Trying to see, if there is a workaround to that.